# Localizing Windows XP for the UK

Tags: windows, localization

I need to run some tests on a UK localized install of Windows XP.  MSDN appears to only provide a single English ISO that defaults to US regional settings.

Must I change anything other than setting the regional config to the UK in order to create a clean, "native" localized machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one English installation CD for XP, for both the US and the UK.

I don't believe that anybody knows exactly what is the difference between (1) specifying either US or UK during the installation of Windows, and (2) changing the locale after Windows was installed. It's most likely that the two are totally equivalent, but there's always a small niggling doubt somewhere.

To be 100% sure of having a clean XP installation the same as done in the UK, I would advice to create a virtual machine containing a new XP installation done with the UK flavor (and especially the UK keyboard). Such an installation is guaranteed not to have any US residues.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder that the regional settings are available during install - exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're testing.

Read the [FAQ on Localization interface packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688177.aspx) as well as the [Locales FAQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688174.aspx), they should lead you in the right direction.

To get the full English UK experience you'll most likely need to download a language pack.